# Deploy a callback API to a VM with IIS

Tags: c#, callback, web-deployment, webapi

I am hoping to deploy a web api to handle callbacks from a 3rd party.

I'm a beginner at C#, but I've written a simple Web API using Visual Studio in order to handle the callbacks.
To test on my dev machine I click the green run button with IIS selected on localhost, and the dll is created. I can feed it some 3rd party test JSON files (using Postman) and the database is updating correctly. So far so good.

Now I'm looking at deployment to a test server, which can receive live (test) callbacks. To do this, I've run up a new VM with a public IP address, installed SQL Express and also installed IIS.

I am assuming the next step is to publish (web deploy) from VS.

But I'm becoming confused with regard to domain name, URL and IP address.
a) Do I need to register a domain name for the IP address? (There is no UI, just the callback endpoint)
b) When setting up the publishing profile for web deploy, what is the Destination URL?

There is a lot of information available on the subject, but there are clearly a few important gaps in my knowledge, and I can't seem to fill 'em.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly - no you do not need a domain name to test your application. You can use a tool like Swagger to test your API. Read more here: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-with-swagger-ui

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Lykke, thanks, but I've already tested the API and I know that it works with Postman. I want to do an end to end test with live (test) data sent by the 3rd party. That is, I need to demonstrate that the 3rd party can interact with the API. But I don't know what to setup on the virtual machine to enable that to happen.

Comment: Also, thanks for your suggestion re Swagger, which would have been a better option for me than Postman - exposing the endpoints in a UI would have made things much easier, and I'll try that in future. But for now the problem remains, how to setup the API on a publicly accessible server?

Comment: Whenever I use the browser to access the API, it tries to download something. If I deliberately misname the GET path, then I get a 404. But if enter the correct name, it doesn't run the code at that path in the API (which displays a couple of records). Instead, it tries to download a file. When I say yes, or save, or open to the download prompt, it says file can't be downloaded. No error message is displayed, but the log appears to show a 500.